# Heroku: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, heroku

I have angular 6 app in my local machine , everything works perfectly as I want, after finishing the project I deployed  it to heroku, when I run my app  here is the link to the app in heroku :[Testing App](https://majeni.herokuapp.com/)

as you can see I get the following error in console browser

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

1. Here is my app structure in github

[App repo in github](https://github.com/gruby-murzyn/agency)

2. for quick reference , Here is server.js

   ```
   const express = require('express');
   const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   const cors = require('cors');
   const path = require('path');
   const app = express();
   const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/majeni/dist/majeni/')));

   app.use(bodyParser.json());

   app.use(cors());



    const forceSSL = function () {
     return function (req, res, next) {
       if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
         return res.redirect(
           ['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join('')
         );
       }
       next();
     }}app.use(forceSSL());

   app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/majeni/dist/majeni/index.html'));
        });

    app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log('Server started on port '+port);
     });
   ```
3. Here is heroku logs.

> 2018-08-16T17:46:38.891333+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/majeni/dist/majeni/index.html'

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you building the Angular app in your Heroku environment? How are you generating the `dist` directory?

Comment: No , cd agency  and then cd majeni  and then ng build  as you can see the directory structure in github

Comment: Right, but are you doing that in your Heroku environment? If you're only doing that on your local machine, then Heroku will not have a copy of that directory. There is no `dist` directory in your checked in code

Comment: Not in heroku environment just in a local machine after `ng-build` i run `git push heroku master`

Comment: so what do I need to do?

Comment: Your `dist` directory is in your `.gitignore`, so it's not being committed. The best option is to provide a `postinstall` script that builds your project https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process

Comment: Thanks works now: can you pust it as answer for future reference if some one will counter the same issue?  here si link : https://majeni.herokuapp.com/home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku is failing to find the `dist` directory, because it is not part of your committed repository. The `dist` directory has been added to the `.gitignore` file.

It's generally a bad idea to commit the `dist` directory, so we should generate it on Heroku.

You can do this by adding a postinstall script in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "ng build"
}
```

More info can be found [in the Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process)